# Multiple Values in a one cell as a combo box

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

I have create a Grid in Extjs in which i am displaying

```
ID
First Name 
Last Name 
LandLine
Mobile
```

But i have multiple values for Land line and Mobile numbers so how can i display it in one cell for example , Land line cell has its multiple values in a one cell and Mobile cell has its own multiple values just like combo box or drop down list. As i don't want to edit rows and just want to show  multiple values in combo box.

Comment: What does the data look like coming from your server? You should post some JSON or XML to show us what it actually looks like if you are hoping for more useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Define a renderer for the column and have it output the multivalue field in any desired format.

Assuming the server is sending an array value for a field name of 'landline':

```
{
    dataIndex: 'landline',
    header: 'LandLine',
    width: 100,
    renderer: function( landline ) {
        return landline.join('<br>');
    }
}
```

If you are declaring types for the fields in your store then you will need to set the field's type to 'auto':

```
{
    name: 'landline',
    type: 'auto'
}
```

Comment: Moreover i want to show numbers in combo box not just like putting a <br> tag inside it

Comment: @Hunt You should be able to put whatever you want in the .join() It only specifies the separator -- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp